# Checkbox Input column css rule always applied to element in the first row

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

I have a table with a column of checkboxes as it appears [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L7y0gzd2/1/). The problem I have is that switching the checked property of any input on any row, the change is always applied on the element in the first row.

So from my understanding the CSS rules

```
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
right: 0px;
}
```

are always applied to row-1.

A possible solution could be adding a rule for each row:

```
#row-1 .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner,
#row-2 .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner,
#row-3 .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner,
#row-4 .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner,
#row-5 .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner,
#row-6 .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {margin-left: 0;}

#row-1 .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch,
#row-2 .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch,
#row-3 .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch,
#row-4 .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch,
#row-5 .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch,
#row-6 .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch { right: 0px; }
```

However I would rather not use this option as it is not the best for maintainability and the number of rows is not known until run-time.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `input` must have an unique `id`, and `label for="that id"`. i.e.

```
<input id="E1" type="checkbox"><label for="E1">...</label>
<input id="E2" type="checkbox"><label for="E2">...</label>
```

**Updated demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/L7y0gzd2/2/